# Why is Python subclass hook called twice when a matching condition is absent

Tags: python

I'm not sure on the behavior of the subclasshook special method when a class used for testing prompts a return of NotImplemented from the subclasshook method. It returns 'False' instead of 'NotImplemented' so I'm assuming that there is some kind of addition function calls from `issubclass(A, B)` in order to return a 'False' value. What exactly happens when NotImplemented is returned from `__subclasshook__` method during a call to `issubclass(A,B)`

```
from abc import ABC, ABCMeta
from abc import abstractmethod

class Foo:
    def __len__(self):
        print("Foo class")
        return 8

class MyIterable(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        print("MyIterable")

    @abstractmethod
    def __iter__(self):
        while False:
            yield None

    def get_iterator(self):
        print("Get iterator")
        return self.__iter__()

    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(cls, C):
        print("Subclass hook called" + "Class: ", cls, "Tested Class: ", C)
        if cls is MyIterable:
            if any("__iter__" in B.__dict__ for B in C.__mro__):
                print("Subclasshook ", C.__mro__[0].__dict__)
                return True
        return NotImplemented

class ConcreteClass(MyIterable):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Concrete class called!")

print(issubclass(Foo, MyIterable))


Subclass hook calledClass:  <class '__main__.MyIterable'> Tested Class:  <class '__main__.Foo'>
Subclass hook calledClass:  <class '__main__.ConcreteClass'> Tested Class:  <class '__main__.Foo'>
False
```

Comment: It would probably help if you printed `cls` and `C` in the subclass hook.

Comment: Okay done it, i seems like the Abstract class subclasshook is called first, followed by any Concrete class subclasshooks when NotImplemented is returned

Comment: Per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.__subclasshook__): `"If it returns NotImplemented, the subclass check is continued with the usual mechanism."`

Comment: And since `ConcreteClass` is a subclass of `MyIterable`, it inherits the subclass hook.

Comment: And what exactly is the usual mechanism

Comment: It makes sense, if you're testing a class for a particular type interface, all Concrete classes are considered the same types of the abstract class but possibly with additional variations. Its just the documentation is not so clear on what the default behaviour for NotImplemented is

Comment: It doesn't seem to be explicitly documented that the "usual mechanism" is to define `Foo` as a subclass of `MyIterable` if `Foo` is a subclass of any known subclass of `MyIterable`.